# Difference in behaviour between whitespace in IFS vs. non-whitespace in IFS

Tags: shell, posix

I know that `read` command splits the input by the characters in the IFS. So if I set IFS as a space then input to the `read` command is split using space as the delimiter. This is shown below.

```
[lone@centos ~]$ IFS=" "
[lone@centos ~]$ read a b c
 foo bar baz qux
[lone@centos ~]$ echo "$a"
foo
[lone@centos ~]$ echo "$b"
bar
[lone@centos ~]$ echo "$c"
baz qux
```

I was expecting that if I make change the IFS to a non-whitespace character, say, a colon and use colon as delimiter in my input, there should be no change in behaviour. But this turned out to be wrong. For example, in the output below, `echo "$a"` is blank. Why?

```
[lone@centos ~]$ IFS=:
[lone@centos ~]$ read a b c
:foo:bar:baz:qux
[lone@centos ~]$ echo "$a"

[lone@centos ~]$ echo "$b"
foo
[lone@centos ~]$ echo "$c"
bar:baz:qux
[lone@centos ~]# echo $c
bar baz qux
```

And why does the output of `echo $c` does not contain the colons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: In the output below, `echo "$a"` is blank. Why?

Because whitespace is special as defined in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) (`2.6.5 Field Splitting`):

> 3a. IFS white space shall be ignored at the beginning and end of the input.

Question 2: And why does the output of `echo $c` does not contain the colons?

Because `bash` performs word splitting in accordance with `IFS` (which is still set to `:`) *before* passing `bar`, `baz` and `qux` as separate arguments to `echo`.